# Improved WGAN-GP training over open-street-network images datasets produces poor results

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have implemented **Improved WGAN-GP** algorithm using keras. The dataset used is a gray-scale open street network images.

Though the model converges in lesser number of iterations , the training results does not improve after some time , particularly with generator the loss does not decrease and is relatively very high compared to discriminator(critic)

```
Epoch 466/2000 :
     Batch 1/4 g loss | d loss : 104.06207 | -4.226562038064003 [-2.113281, 104.71014, -106.92572, 0.102302775] - Batch run time : 4.135012865066528 s.
     Batch 2/4 g loss | d loss : 94.39241 | -4.960913240909576 [-2.4804566, 91.04619, -93.64499, 0.11834401] - Batch run time : 6.0274436473846436 s.
     Batch 3/4 g loss | d loss : 92.28177 | -3.1542448699474335 [-1.5771224, 87.14488, -88.7628, 0.0407975] - Batch run time : 4.139840841293335 s.
     Batch 4/4 g loss | d loss : 126.10479 | -4.55475278198719 [-2.2773764, 116.78906, -119.262726, 0.19628696] - Batch run time : 1.2910008430480957 s.
Saving models ...
Epoch 467/2000 :
     Batch 1/4 g loss | d loss : 117.81751 | -4.348973780870438 [-2.1744869, 114.43104, -116.91664, 0.31111643] - Batch run time : 4.134741544723511 s.
     Batch 2/4 g loss | d loss : 112.36156 | -4.238630764186382 [-2.1193154, 111.77963, -113.97125, 0.072304495] - Batch run time : 6.4081127643585205 s.
     Batch 3/4 g loss | d loss : 112.64513 | -4.389123365283012 [-2.1945617, 110.87658, -113.19942, 0.12827618] - Batch run time : 4.130998611450195 s.
     Batch 4/4 g loss | d loss : 129.88966 | -4.145997077226639 [-2.0729985, 124.60733, -126.95893, 0.2786021] - Batch run time : 1.3250582218170166 s.
```

Please check the gist of my implemented algorithm [here](https://gist.github.com/bhavyalatha26/3142d6fcad33515af89ac6e9ad003677),  and the dataset used for my training can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qWM3VrloOBMhqNJd3cLbDp8Af21nf7iq?usp=sharing)

My end goal was to generate images with resolution upto 512 or 1024 (not sure if this is possible with WGAN-GP algorithm), however I ran this algorithm for 256 x 256 first , but could not produce good results.

PFA a sample result after **2000 iterations**. This is a 8x4 grid image showing batch results of batch size 32.
[image]

Below are the ***original images*** of the same 
[image] 
Can some one help me correct my algorithm and hyper parameters (if any) to train my GAN model with the data set mentioned in the above links.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Look for mode collapse, adjust also learning rate, amount of noise and noise distribution, optimizers. There are ways to overcome mode collapse. See specially slides 37 and 38, Tips and Tricks for Training GANs [Generative Adversarial Networks](https://www.slideshare.net/RubensZimbres/gans-deep-learning-summer-school)

- Normalize data (-1,1)
- Output of Generative Neural Net: tanh
- Sample from gaussian distribution instead of normal distribution
- Mini batches
- Use Batch Normalization
- Use Adam optimizer in Generator
- Use SGD in Discriminator
- Add Dropout in Generator

Comment: Hi @Rubens thanks for the quick reply . I did face mode collapse issue with DC-GAN so I upgrade it to WGAN-GP mentioned above.
I did follow all the above tips , except using SGD for discriminator ( as the proposed architecture recommends Adam for both critic and generator)

Comment: Hi @Bhavya, are you using KL Divergence in loss ?

Comment: I use Wasserstein loss and WGAN-GP loss